# How to place some text in parallel to a picture defined under `<figure>` tag

Tags: html, css

I have a `<figure>` tag and now I have to place some text right across(parallel) to the image, I tried but I am  not able to achieve it.

HTML:
`<figure class=frame id="box">
        <span class="helper"></span><img class= "profile1" src="" alt="my img"/>
        <figcaption id="text">Your Name</figcaption>
        </figure>`

I wan to place a `<p>` tag that contains some text and display it to the right of the image(in parallel)

The necessary CSS for it:

```
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 95%;

}
.frame {
    height: 100px;      
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;

}

.profile1 {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: left;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    justify-content: space-around;
     text-align: justify;
    width: [width of img];
}

#box {
    width: 1460px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 150px; 
    box-sizing: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

#text{

    text-align: left;
    margin: -1em 1.65em;
}
```

Comment: In parallel...so you want the letters going vertical like a column?

Comment: No, I actually meant, the text line should go right across the image. The below solution helped me btw. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the p text and float it left

```css
p{margin:0;
float:left;
}

.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 95%;

}
.frame {
    height: 100px;      
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center; 
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;

}

.profile1 {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: left;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    justify-content: space-around;
     text-align: justify;
    width: [width of img];
}

#box {
    width: 1460px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 150px; 
    box-sizing: 15px;
    border: 1px solid;

}

#text{

    text-align: left;
    margin: -1em 1.65em;
}
```

```html
<figure class=frame id="box">
        <span class="helper"></span><img class= "profile1" src="" alt="my img"/><p>Text Here</p>
        <figcaption id="text">Your Name</figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't able to figure such silly thing. Anyways, I appreciate your help.